# insert 2 column primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I want to insert 2 column primary key ( X and Y) in table A. X is inserted from table B and Y inserted from a fixed value..

```
INSERT INTO A
  (X,Y) 
SELECT W 
  FROM table B, '1'
```

Answer (score 5):

You were close:

```
INSERT INTO A
  (X,Y) 
SELECT W, '1'
  FROM table B
```

Define the static value -- in this example, the text "1" -- as a column in the SELECT clause.

Only one `FROM` clause per `SELECT` clause.  Additional SELECTs need to be within brackets/parenthesis...